# How to get the sum of elements from a request with Propel?

Tags: php, symfony, propel

I'm trying to get the sum of variables contained in my object, and I don't know how to do it. I know it's not very clear, so here is an example.

I'm doing a request to obtain all discounts from one User. I now want to get the sum of all the discounts he had. In SQL, it would be:

```sql
SELECT SUM(c.discount_price) AS SumDiscounts FROM my_table c GROUP BY c.user_id
```

How can I do it in propel?

Comment: I know [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) can help you.

Comment: @DocRoms not at all. He is looking for a Propel solution, not a SQL solution. (btw, please avoid W3schools ... http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
    $collection = MyTableQuery::create()
        ->withColumn('SUM(c.discount_price)', 'SumDiscounts')
        ->groupByUserId()
        ->find();
```

Comment: Thankes, unfortunately i almost had the same propel query and it doesn't provide me the good result..don't know why though, here is the generated request :    SELECT users ...., SUM(discount_price) AS SumDiscounts 
FROM `user_discounts` 
GROUP BY user_discounts.USER_ID

Comment: @BillSmith please specify for what table is alias `c` used